# Resultado diferente al usar parseFloat

Tags: javascript

Necesito solo coger dos decimales de un numero con el método toFixed(2) y para ello tengo que convertir a parseFloat los números porque sino me falla el método toFixed.
El problema es que me dan números erróneos y no se por qué.

```
var x=0;
var y=0;
var T=127.76;
var c=63.88;
var ci=110.64;
```

Sin usar parseFloat y toFixed;

```
var x1=x+ci;//110.64809081046089
var y1=y-c;//-63.882705014737745
var x2=x1+c;//174.53079582519862
var y2=y1+ci;//46.76538579572314
```

Al usar parseFloat y toFixed el resultado da erroneo;

```
var x1=x+ci;//110.64809081046089
x1=parseFloat(x1);//110.64809081046089
x1=x1.toFixed(2);//110.65
var y1=y-c;//-63.882705014737745
y1=parseFloat(y1);//-63.882705014737745
y1=y1.toFixed(2);//-63.88
```

Aquí ya me calcula mal las operaciones

```
var x2=x1+c;//110.6563.882705014737745 Y DEBERIA DAR 174.53079582519862
x2=parseFloat(x2);
x2=x2.toFixed(2);
var y2=y1+ci;//-63.88 Y DEBERIA DAR 46.76538579572314
y2=parseFloat(y2);
y2=y2.toFixed(2);
```

No entiendo por qué estos resultados son erróneos.

Comment: tu pregunta es porque es diferente o como solucionarlo?

Comment: A mi parecer la pregunta no es un duplicado de la que se menciona, el problema no es los números flotantes, sino el tipo de datos

Answer (score 4):

El problema que tienes es que se está liando entre los float y los que el considera que son string.

La solución sería hacerles el parseo a todas las variables al principio

```
var x=parseFloat(0);
var y=parseFloat(0);
var T=parseFloat(127.76);
var c=parseFloat(63.88);
var ci=parseFloat(110.64);
```

o hacerselo a todos durante las operaciones

```
var x2=x1+parseFloat(c);
x2=parseFloat(x2);
x2=x2.toFixed(2);
var y2=y1+parseFloat(ci);
y2=parseFloat(y2);
y2=y2.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo que te está pasando es un error bastante frecuente cuando se opera con variables que contienen valores numéricos. Y es que hay que tener muy claro el tipo de contenido con el que estamos trabajando. Este es uno de tus resultados erróneos:

```
var x2=x1+c;//110.6563.882705014737745 Y DEBERIA DAR 174.53079582519862
```

Lo que tú esperas es que la variable **x2** pase a contener la suma de la variable **x1** y la variable **c**. Y aquí tenemos el problema. La variable **c** en tu código se está tratando como un  string, por lo que en vez de sumar su valor a **x1** lo está concatenando, dando como resultado lo que nos pones:

```
110.6563.882705014737745
```

Lo que yo haría sería forzar a que **c** sea también un número haciéndole un `parseFloat()` y lo mismo con las demás variables que operen en las fórmulas que te estén dando resultados erróneos.